# Box V2 API - Where is lock/unlock?

Tags: locking, box-api, unlock

There is a note in the [developer road map](http://developers.box.com/roadmap/) from December of 2013 saying, "**Lock/Unlock** – We’ve added support for locking and unlocking files into the V2 API."

I've been all through the V2 API (for c#) and cannot find it anywhere.  I expected to find something in the **BoxFilesManager** class or as something you would pass to **UpdateInformationAsync** within the **BoxFileRequest** class.

So is there a way to lock/unlock a file?

Answer (score 0):

Great question.  In order to see the current lock status of a file do a

```
GET https://api.box.com/2.0/files/7435988481/?fields=lock
```

If there is no lock on the file, you'll get something like this back:

```
{
    "type": "file",
    "id": "7435988481",
    "etag": "0",
    "lock": null
}
```

If you want to lock a file, you need to do a PUT (update) on the /files/ endpoint with a body that tells us what type of lock, and when to release it.  Like this:

```
PUT https://api.box.com/2.0/files/7435988481/?fields=lock

{"lock": {
"expires_at" : "2014-05-29T19:03:04-07:00",
  "is_download_prevented": true
}
}
```

You'll get a response confirming your lock was created:

```
{
    "type": "file",
    "id": "7435988481",
    "etag": "1",
    "lock": {
        "type": "lock",
        "id": "14516545",
        "created_by": {
            "type": "user",
            "id": "13130406",
            "name": "Peter Rexer gmail",
            "login": "prexer@gmail.com"
        },
        "created_at": "2014-05-29T18:03:04-07:00",
        "expires_at": "2014-05-29T19:03:04-07:00",
        "is_download_prevented": true
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how to determine the status using GET/PUT.  Is there a C# API call as well?

Comment: Uh... C# gurus of the world? Anyone feel like adding it to the SDK?  Probably should file a feature request.. either https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2 or https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2

Comment: JHoerr is out, stopped maintain that library when Box came out with their own.

Comment: That's because JHoerr has started helping maintain the Box OSS one

Comment: @PeterSmith, I'm confused; I thought that the C# Box V2 API was maintained by Box. It sounds like NOT, if you're asking for help with it.

Comment: What does the GET look like if there is a lock?

Comment: @kberson  GET response is shown in the answer above in the case of a lock (2nd) and without a lock (first response).  Box JSON is roughly in-out symmetric.  Box will ignore the fields you aren't allowed to set (like created_at).  You'll get the same response from a GET as you do from the lock-creating PUT.

Comment: yep, sorry, brain fart that I didn't see the nose in front of my face.

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't a lock/unlock yet, I created a Lock Manager based on the existing managers:

```
class BoxCloudLockManager : BoxResourceManager
{
    #region Lock/Unlock Classes
    [DataContract]
    internal class BoxLockRequestInfo
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        //[DataMember(Name = "expires_at")]
        //public string ExpiresAt { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "is_download_prevented")]
        public bool IsDownloadPrevented { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    internal class BoxLockRequest
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "lock")]
        public BoxLockRequestInfo Lock { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion

    const string LockFileString = "{0}/?fields=lock";

    public BoxCloudLockManager(IBoxConfig config, IBoxService service, IBoxConverter converter, IAuthRepository auth) 
        : base(config, service, converter, auth)
    {
    }

    public async Task<BoxLockInfo> LockAsync(string documentId,bool isDownloadPrevented = true)
    {
        var lockRequest = new BoxLockRequest { Lock = new BoxLockRequestInfo { Status = "lock", IsDownloadPrevented = isDownloadPrevented } };

        BoxRequest request = new BoxRequest(_config.FilesEndpointUri, string.Format(LockFileString, documentId))
            .Method(RequestMethod.Put)
            .Payload(_converter.Serialize(lockRequest));

        IBoxResponse<BoxLockInfo> response = await ToResponseAsync<BoxLockInfo>(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return response.ResponseObject;
    }

    public async Task<BoxLockInfo> UnlockAsync(string documentId)
    {
        BoxRequest request = new BoxRequest(_config.FilesEndpointUri, string.Format(LockFileString, documentId))
            .Method(RequestMethod.Put)
            .Payload("{\"lock\":null}");

        IBoxResponse<BoxLockInfo> response = await ToResponseAsync<BoxLockInfo>(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return response.ResponseObject;
    }

    public async Task<BoxLockInfo> GetLockInfoAsync(string documentId)
    {
        BoxRequest request = new BoxRequest(_config.FilesEndpointUri, string.Format(LockFileString, documentId))
            .Method(RequestMethod.Get);

        IBoxResponse<BoxLockInfo> response = await ToResponseAsync<BoxLockInfo>(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return response.ResponseObject;
    }
}
```

I derived a class from BoxClient, adding a LockManager and instantiate it within the Constructor.

Here is the Lock Info:

```
[DataContract]
public class BoxLockedBy
{
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class BoxLockDetails
{
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "created_by")]
    public BoxLockedBy CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "created_at")]
    public string CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "expires_at")]
    public string ExpiresAt { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "is_download_prevented")]
    public bool IsDownloadPrevented { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class BoxLockInfo
{
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "etag")]
    public string Etag { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "lock")]
    public BoxLockDetails LockDetails { get; set; }
}
```